# Sencha Touch list-search does not work

Tags: list, sencha-touch

I am trying out the list-search example that comes along with the latest Sencha Touch 1.1.0 open source distributin, and I am getting this error:

```
Ext.List: itemTpl is a required configuration.
[Break On This Error] throw new Error("Ext.List: itemTpl is a required configuration.");
sencha...ebug.js (line 23220)
WebKitPoint is not defined
[Break On This Error] var point = window.webkitConve...age(this.dom, new WebKitPoint(0, 0)); 
sencha...ebug.js (line 11612)
```

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding an `itemTpl` to your list. As the error message indicates, this is required for the list component to work.

I've made a few Sencha Touch screencasts which should help: one on the [list component](http://vimeo.com/19245335), and a two part series on [Xtemplates](http://vimeo.com/16289757) ([part one](http://vimeo.com/16289757) and [part two](http://vimeo.com/16289990)).

Answer (score 1):

Change the 'tpl' item from listConfig to itemTpl and the list will at least render. Looking at that example though, I'm not sure it functions. It has the search field as a docked item in the list, but I don't think you can dock items in a list. It should be wrappered in a panel, with the docked items in the panel, and the list as a panel item. James Pearce shows an example of how to do the layout in the PhoneGap MVC with Sencha tutorial:

http://www.sencha.com/learn/Tutorial:A_Sencha_Touch_MVC_application_with_PhoneGap

It says in there that:

> Unfortunately, it's not possible to dock a toolbar directly onto an Ext.List, hence the panel wrapper.

So it looks like maybe that list-search example has just gotten outdated (I'm looking at the 1.1.0 release as well).

Answer (score 1):

I modified index.js to function correctly, using mikerowehl suggestions. Here it is if anyone needs it:

```
    Ext.regModel('Contact', {
            fields: ['firstName', 'lastName']
        });


    myStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
            model  : 'Contact',
            sorters: 'lastName',
            getGroupString : function(record) {
                return record.get('lastName')[0];
            },

            data: [
                {firstName: 'Tommy',   lastName: 'Maintz'},
                {firstName: 'Rob',     lastName: 'Dougan'},
                {firstName: 'Ed',      lastName: 'Spencer'},
                {firstName: 'Jamie',   lastName: 'Avins'},
                {firstName: 'Aaron',   lastName: 'Conran'},
                {firstName: 'Dave',    lastName: 'Kaneda'},
                {firstName: 'Michael', lastName: 'Mullany'},
                {firstName: 'Abraham', lastName: 'Elias'},
                {firstName: 'Jay',     lastName: 'Robinson'},
                {firstName: 'Tommy',   lastName: 'Maintz'},
                {firstName: 'Rob',     lastName: 'Dougan'},
                {firstName: 'Ed',      lastName: 'Spencer'},
                {firstName: 'Jamie',   lastName: 'Avins'},
                {firstName: 'Aaron',   lastName: 'Conran'},
                {firstName: 'Dave',    lastName: 'Kaneda'},
                {firstName: 'Michael', lastName: 'Mullany'},
                {firstName: 'Abraham', lastName: 'Elias'},
                {firstName: 'Jay',     lastName: 'Robinson'}
            ]
    });

    Ext.setup({
    tabletStartupScreen: 'tablet_startup.png',
    phoneStartupScreen : 'phone_startup.png',    
    icon       : 'icon.png',
    glossOnIcon: false,

    onReady: function() {
         var listConfig = {
            dockedItems: [
                {
                    xtype: 'toolbar',
                    dock : 'top',

                    items: [
                        {xtype: 'spacer'},
                        {
                            xtype      : 'textfield',
                            placeHolder: 'Search...',
                            listeners  : {
                                scope: this,

                                keyup: function(field) {
                                    var value = field.getValue();

                                    if (!value) {
                                        myStore.filterBy(function() {
                                            return true;
                                        });
                                    } else {
                                        var searches = value.split(' '),
                                            regexps  = [],
                                            i;

                                        for (i = 0; i < searches.length; i++) {
                                            if (!searches[i]) return;
                                            regexps.push(new RegExp(searches[i], 'i'));
                                        };

                                        myStore.filterBy(function(record) {
                                            var matched = [];

                                            for (i = 0; i < regexps.length; i++) {
                                                var search = regexps[i];

                                                if (record.get('firstName').match(search) || record.get('lastName').match(search)) matched.push(true);
                                                else matched.push(false);
                                            };

                                            if (regexps.length > 1 && matched.indexOf(false) != -1) {
                                                return false;
                                            } else {
                                                return matched[0];
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {xtype: 'spacer'},                        
                    ]
                }
            ]
        };

        if (!Ext.is.Phone) {
            new Ext.Panel(Ext.apply(listConfig, {
                floating     : true,
                width        : 380,
                height       : 420,
                centered     : true,
                modal        : true,
                hideOnMaskTap: false,
                items:
        {
            xtype:'list',
            itemTpl : '<tpl for="."><div class="contact">{firstName} <strong>{lastName}</strong></div></tpl>',

            itemSelector: 'div.contact',
            singleSelect: true,
            grouped     : true,

            store: myStore,
        },
            })).show();
        } else {
            new Ext.Panel(Ext.apply(listConfig, {                       
                fullscreen: true,
                items:
        {
            xtype:'list',
            itemTpl : '<tpl for="."><div class="contact">{firstName} <strong>{lastName}</strong></div></tpl>',
            itemSelector: 'div.contact',
            singleSelect: true,
            grouped     : true,
            store: myStore,
        },
            }));
        }
    }
});
```